# Using Eclipse to edit javascript, 'Phaser not defined'

Tags: javascript, eclipse, phaser-framework

I am trying to use the Eclipse IDE to develop games in JavaScript using the Phaser game framework. I have a simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Game</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a simple Phaser script (base.js) that simply creates a blank canvas:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1280, 720, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {
}

function create() {
}

function update() {
}
```

And of course, I have the Phaser framework in a separate file (phaser.min.js).

This all work, and when I run a local web server and go to the page a blank black Phaser canvas is created. However, in Eclipse, the first line of the javascript file is underlined in red, with the error `'Phaser' is not defined.`

When editing Javascript in Eclipse, how do you 'import' (for lack of a better term) another javascript file for use in validation? Code completion for Phaser would be useful to, but isn't necessary.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dsiclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started)

I suggest you that you try [Tern Phaser support](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Phaser-support) with tern.java which gives features like completion, validation for Phaser inside Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I was literally just waiting for tern to install when I read your message! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would hazard a guess that out of the box, Eclipse doesn't have Javascript support given that it's primarily a Java IDE.

Try adding the JSDT plugin: https://eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/

Or:

Giving another editor a try, one of the IntelliJ IDEs: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already have JSDT installed. I will try using another IDE though, and see if the problem is to do with the IDE or with Phaser